# Unable to change the focusColor property of Input Decoration in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to change the color of the TextField on Focus (or whenever user tap on it). I'm using focusColor property of InputDecoration but it is not working as expected. Can you please help me with it . I'm using the code below :

```
    return Card(
  child: Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      primaryColor: CustomColors.grey,
    ),
    child: TextField(
      autofocus: widget.autofocus,
      onSubmitted: (value) => setState(() {
        if (onSearch != null) {
          onSearch(value);
        }
      }),

      controller: searchTextController,
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
        if (widget.onChange != null) {
          widget.onChange!(value);
        }
      }),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 0.5,
                color: CustomTheme.searchBarCardBorderColor(context))),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: CustomTheme.searchBarfocusBorderColor(context))),
        focusColor: CustomTheme.searchBarCursorNFocusColor(context),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: focusColor property seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I met with the same problem before. The bottom line is that you need to change the default theme. So, you can use:

```
child: new Theme(
          data: new ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.red,
          ),
          child: new TextField(
      controller: searchTextController,
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
        if (widget.onChange != null) {
          widget.onChange!(value);
        }
      }),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hoverColor: Theme.searchBarhoverColor(context),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 6, bottom: 6),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3.0)),
        ),
        ));
```

Just noticed: you used `border: InputBorder.none` so your border is turned off

Comment: If that doesn't help, try changing other border properties

Comment: Also just noticed: you use border: InputBorder.none? It turns off the border

Comment: tried this but still no luck

Comment: I've updated the code , you can have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  TextField(
            controller: searchTextController,
                    onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                  if (widget.onChange != null) {
                  widget.onChange!(value);
                 }
                       }),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 1),
                      ),
                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: it is only changing the color of border not the textField

Answer (score 0):

For me adding a FocusNode was the solution:

create a FocusNode:

```
late FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode()
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
```

add it to your TextField:

```
TextFormField(
  focusNode: focusNode,
  controller: textEditingController,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
     filled:true,
     fillColor:focusNode.hasFocus? Colors.red,
     ),
   ),
```